# $("div[attribute=[var]") not working

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/S9TCc/ - that has three divs.  The second two have a "popup_name" attribute that has the value "pu1".  The first div has a rollover handler that has a "rollover_target" attribute whose value is also "pu1".

The idea is that when you rollover box1, its rollover_target attribute specifies what divs are to displayed, i.e., those with a popup_name attribute of "pu1".

ro$ in line 6 collects the divs we need to display.  This line works fine, finding 2 divs. 
ro$ in line 7 should, it seems, do exactly the same thing, since it just uses a variable with "pu1' instead of the string "pu1".  But it brings back 0 divs.

Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks

```
$('#box1').hover(function() {
    var rollover_target;
    var ro$;
    debugger;
    rollover_target  = $(this).attr('rollover_target');
    ro$=$("div[popup_name='pu1']");  // works
    ro$=$("div[popup_name=rollover_target]");
    x=1;        // so debugger doesn't return before results of above line are seen
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation when you use a string literal with a variable

```
ro$=$('div[popup_name="' + rollover_target + '"]');
```